Telegram bot constantly shows "Getting updates..." and does not start the game
I'm developing a Telegram bot that successfully responds to commands and sends messages, but it fails to open the game upon pressing the start button. Instead, the bot remains stuck at "Getting updates..." without progressing to handle incoming messages or callbacks. Here's a simplified version of my Python code:
import requests
import time
import json

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
GAME_URL = 'https://www.yyyyyyy.info/index.html'

URL = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}"
offset = None  # Initialized offset

def send_message(chat_id, text, keyboard=None):
    url = f"{URL}/sendMessage"
    if keyboard:
        payload = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard)}
    else:
        payload = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text}
    requests.post(url, json=payload)

def answer_callback_query(callback_query_id, url):
    answer_url = f"{url}?game_url={GAME_URL}"
    response = requests.get(f"{URL}/answerCallbackQuery", params={'callback_query_id': callback_query_id, 'url': answer_url})
    print(f"Answer Callback Query Response: {response.text}")

def start_game(chat_id):
    # Placeholder function for starting the game
    game_message = "The game is starting! Please wait..."
    send_message(chat_id, game_message)

while True:
    try:
        print("Getting updates...")
        response = requests.get(f"{URL}/getUpdates", params={'offset': offset}).json()
        if response.get('ok'):
            updates = response['result']
            print(f"Received updates: {updates}")  # Debugging line to see received updates
            for update in updates:
                print(f"Processing update: {update}")
                if 'message' in update:
                    chat_id = update['message']['chat']['id']
                    text = update['message'].get('text', '')

                    keyboard = {
                        'inline_keyboard': [[{'text': 'Start game', 'callback_data': 'start_game'}]]
                    }
                    if text == '/start' or text.startswith('/'):
                        print(f"Sending welcome message to chat {chat_id}")
                        send_message(chat_id, 'Welcome! Press the button to start the game.', keyboard)
                    else:
                        print(f"Sending unknown command message to chat {chat_id}")
                        send_message(chat_id, 'Unknown command. Press the button to start the game.', keyboard)
                elif 'callback_query' in update:
                    callback_query_id = update['callback_query']['id']
                    if update['callback_query']['data'] == 'start_game':
                        print(f"Responding to callback query {callback_query_id} to start the game")
                        start_game(update['callback_query']['message']['chat']['id'])
                        answer_callback_query(callback_query_id, GAME_URL)

                    # Update offset after processing callback_query
                    offset = update['callback_query']['id'] + 1

                # Update offset after processing updates
                offset = update['update_id'] + 1

        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch updates: {response}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    time.sleep(1)  # Wait before next request

The issue seems to be with the offset variable not updating correctly after processing updates, causing the bot to repeatedly fetch the same updates. How can I modify my code to ensure the bot correctly handles incoming messages and opens the game upon pressing the "Start game" button?
Feel free to adjust the details as necessary. Good luck with your bot development!

have you debugged your code. For example if the response.get('ok') returns false, then you don't do anything, so you will only see the Getting updates message. You need to debug your code line by line and see where it differs from the expected behavior.

@Elerium115 Thanks for the answer, I will add additional outputs and complete the question within an hour

@Elerium115 I received such an output, and so far I can't figure out how to output more information. Is it useful?
https://sun9-61.userapi.com/impg/9iQx6_lrPDavAxjhJ7jbY7AP_Toki9zM1KWvXQ/6BvedftgTo8.jpg?size=1318x516&quality=96&sign=b52b9acc8b1958a651f23858c592cdb8&type=album

No, a link in a comment is not useful. Instead you should edit your question and post any relevant information there, properly formatted. However, this information you posted in the link shows that your code is not stuck with the message "getting updates" which makes your question outdated. You should edit your question to reflect your problem providing all available info there

I checked everything and found the error output. it's about the url. why is it incorrect?
Answer Callback Query Response: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: URL_INVALID"}  @Elerium115

Ok, so don't pass an invalid url to the request.
